# How to typecast TObject to LongInt?

Tags: object, casting, overflow, long-integer, lazarus

okay I have a TStringList variable called CaLlist and use it as follows in my code.

```
CalList.strings[i] := "Something";
CalList.Objects[i] := TObject(22.3);

rawval := PtrInt(CalList.Objects[i]); <<------- Error raised here.
```

I am using FPC 2.6.2 Lazarus 1.0.16. This code compiles and runs okay but when I step through the code **rawval** is set to be some astronomical negative number not 22.3 as I expect it to be.

So, what am I doing wrong? Is there is a solution for this issue?

Comment: `22.3` is not the integer value.

Comment: @Abelisto Oh, it only takes Integer not real or floating point value.

Comment: @Abelisto I tried to put in Integer value like 3, but it won't take it. It actually wants Real Value or it won't compile.

Comment: [Topic: Converting TObject to Real and vice versa](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,30191) Is it yours? And look at [Data Structures, Containers, Collections](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Data_Structures,_Containers,_Collections) - may be you will find something more appropriate for your task then TStringList.

Comment: @Abelisto yep that is my topic at Lazarus forum. :) I saw your username and realized it was you. :) okay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast the `.Object[i]` to double (double size = 8 bytes = register size on x86_64) or single (single size = 4 bytes = register size on x86).

Example:

```
program Project1;

uses classes;

{$IFDEF CPU32}
type PtrFloat = Single;
{$ELSE}
type PtrFloat = Double;
{$ENDIF}

var
  CalList: TStringList;
  rawval: PtrFloat;

begin

  CalList := TStringList.Create;
  CalList.Add('');
  rawval := 22.3;
  CalList.strings[0] := 'Something';
  CalList.Objects[0] := TObject(rawval);
  rawval := PtrFloat(CalList.Objects[0]);

  writeln(rawval);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: We moved beyond using 32 bit machines. So, I bypassed having to define type and used Double straight and it works fine. Thank you.